# select object related to image through the outliner

Tags: image, outliner

I am trying to find the object in the scene that has the tree.png image on it, This is quite a big scene and some images names are obscure and not as recognizable as 'tree'.
My question is... is it possible to select the object that the image is connected to through the **outline -> Blender File -> search**

[image]

When clicking on the image (or right-clicking) none of the options works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First two steps due to a bug which I didn't expect.

1. Grab debug.py from here: https://developer.blender.org/T98252
2. Replace `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender <your blender version>\<your blender version>\scripts\addons\amaranth\scene\debug.py`
3. Open Blender, enable Amaranth toolset add-on.
4. In **scene** tab, open **scene debug**. In list users for datablock section select **image**, choose **tree.png**  and press the button **List Users for Datablock**. A list of users will be shown:

[image]

Comment: Nice one! Although I do think it should be easier than that, like right-clicking the tree.png and get the user list.  Thanks for the answer, I wasn't aware of the amaranth toolset, I will explore it a bit further